# How to get Image/Asset URL in Matrix?

Tags: assets, matrix, entry

I have got a problem with an asset field in a Matrix in an _entry template.
The Matrix is for a step-by-step feature. Each step has his own image.
So the asset field in my Matrix calls: `stepImage`.

Now in my `_entry` template I loop over the step Matrix like:

```
{% for row in entry.steps %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

In this loop I try to get the asset URL like:

```
  {% set image = row.stepImage.first() %}
  {% if image %}
      {{image.url}}
  {% endif %}
```

but it does not work. If i dump it, it returns `bool(false)`.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest giving the Matrix [templating](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields#templating) docs a once-over.

If `steps` is the name of your Matrix field, then `{% for row in entry.steps %}` is going to be looping over each of the Matrix blocks you've defined.

Then you'd want to check for the stepImage asset field in the correct block. i.e.

```
{% for block in entry.steps %}
    {% if block.type == 'myBlock' %}
         {% set image = block.stepImage.one() %}
       
         {% if image %}
             {{image.url}}
         {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```